# Postgres CASE statement not working in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, case

I've written a query in postgres (on PGAdmin) and I'd like to put it in SSMS2012 for reporting purposes however it doesn't seem to allow the CASE statement, this is my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY (POSTGRESQL,
                'SELECT 
                     Table1 AS Table_1,
                     CASE Table2 
                        WHEN 75887 THEN ''1''
                        WHEN 75888 THEN ''2''
                        WHEN 75889 THEN ''3'' 
                        WHEN 75890 THEN ''4''
                        WHEN 75891 THEN ''5''
                        WHEN 75892 THEN ''6''
                     END AS Table_2,
                     DateTable1 AS DateTime
                 FROM SuperTable1 ')
```

And I'm getting the error:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "POSTGRESQL" returned
>   message "Requested conversion is not supported.".
>   Msg 7341, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot get the current row value of column "[MSDASQL].table_2" from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "POSTGRESQL".

I've noticed if I remove the whole case statement it has no issues retreiving the data in the columns in the `SELECT` statement and the whole thing (including the `CASE` statement) works fine in PGAdmin.

Comment: Case expression, not case statement...

Comment: Perhaps you need to do CASE WHEN Table2 =  75887 THEN ...WHEN WHEN Table2 =  ...?

Comment: Is Table1 a field name? If not, you might have to quote it like ''Table1''. Also, I am not entirely sure if DateTable1 should be written as to_char(DateTable1, ''YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'') - something to try

Comment: table1 is the field name yes, unfortunately writing to_char(DateTable1, ''YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'') didn't fix the issue, still getting the same error

Comment: Do you really have a _column_ named `Table2`? - extremely strange naming conventions

Comment: No, I just rename all the columns before I write the query online for security reasons as required by my employer. Not quite sure why I write them as table* when they're columns but I've been doing it for years...

Comment: Is `Table2` a nvarchar or int field?

Comment: First try to specify the type of returned text value (ex. `WHEN 75887 THEN ''1''::text`). There could by problems with linked server in that mater. Secondl if still getting error try to specyfiy `COLLATE`. By the way what is your coLlation settings in both MSSQL and PostgreSQL?

Comment: @Mike One more thing. Is Table1 a text column? If so, what is your longest value there (in terms of characters count)?

Answer (score 0):

Try simplify the query

Run 4 separated querys to determinate which one is giving you the problem.
Also try using `1` instead of `''1''`

```
SELECT Table1 AS Table_1

SELECT DateTable1 AS DateTime

SELECT 
    CASE Table2 
    WHEN 75887 THEN 1   
    END AS Table_2

SELECT 
    CASE Table2 
    WHEN 75887 THEN ''1''
    END AS Table_2
```

Comment: I suggest you run the simple querys in my update to determinate with is the exact part giving you the problems